# SQL Server Full-Text search Empty catalog

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, azure-sql-database, freetext

I'm trying to get a full-text search running on SQL Server in Azure.

My data is in a `varbinary(max)` with all columns containing data. The data is strings of html.

The `SearchableData` column is computed and filled using:

`CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),[Title] + [Body])`

Doing a select and a convert back yields data.

I would like to utilize the built in html filter of SQL Server.

If I do the following I can search and everything works, however, without a filter:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
    ON ArticleContent (Body LANGUAGE 0, Title LANGUAGE 0) 
       KEY INDEX PK_ArticleContent ON AcademyFTS 
       WITH (STOPLIST = SYSTEM, CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO)
```

However, I want to be able to utalize the .html filtering.

I've created the following:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG AcademyFTS WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF AS DEFAULT
```

and

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
    ON ArticleContent (SearchableData TYPE COLUMN FileExtension LANGUAGE 0) 
       KEY INDEX PK_ArticleContent ON AcademyFTS 
       WITH (STOPLIST = SYSTEM, CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO)
```

However the catalog is empty and I don't get any results back from a simple search

```
SELECT * 
FROM ArticleContent 
WHERE FREETEXT(SearchableData, 'wiki')
```

I've been using these two guides:

[Hands on Full-Text Search in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/hands-full-text-search-sql-server/)

[How to implement a full-text search on HTML documents with Microsoft SQL Server](http://blog.leifbattermann.de/2016/09/23/howto-implement-full-text-search-html-documents-microsoft-sql-server/#disqus_thread)

Comment: It should be added that the filters are installed and I've also had a look at Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Have you tested storing HTML data as XML? Search results won’t include tagnames, attribute names, or words within comments

Comment: I will have a try. I have gotten it to work with nvarchar fields but then I get no filtering.

Comment: http://developmentnow.com/2006/08/12/sql-server-2005-full-text-search-on-html-documents/

Comment: They are using image and not varbinary(max), I do the same thing as they do. I still don't get results back. Something is wierd. Searching in varchar works just fine if I set the FT search index on body/title in this case. I don't get filtering however..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!

You can't full-text search on a computed column! :)

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/full-text-indexes-on-nonpersisted-computed-columns-are-not-allowed?view=sql-server-2014)